# Monitoring replication status from the subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication, monitoring

I have two databases that are populated by our vendor using replication from their databases. I do not have access to their distributor db. But I want to monitor from our end whether the data has been refreshed as per schedule.

Is there a way to do this? All the blogs/posts I have seen require access to the distribution db.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the canary method to monitor replication status on the subscriber. Check it out [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/monitoring-sql-server-transactional-replication/) in the "Easy Replication Monitoring: Alert on Latency with Canary Tables" section.

With this method, you would be writing to a table on the publisher that has just one column. Update the table every minute with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Monitor the table on the subscriber and fire off an alert if the difference between the table and the current time has exceeded your threshold.

Comment: I don't have access to the vendor server/publication. So can't change anything. I was looking to more easier method :). I don't even have select access to the Distributor.

Comment: @Prashant seems like the principle is still sound though. If the vendor is unwilling to put a canary table up in lieu of providing you direct access to the replication monitor, could you try base-lining a canary *record*? For example: you set a process to trigger a track-able data change at a known key-value location. Then alert yourself if that data change occurs outside your baseline?

Comment: Does the publisher have any tables that get very frequent inserts that include a column for the creation date of the row? You can use a table like that in lieu of a canary table. The key is that the table must have very frequent inserts.

Comment: Thanks @TaraKizer for the work around. Though I wish MS would provide some DMV/systable for it.

Answer (score -1):

If your replicated environment are supposed to assume the same amount of work and be exactly the same as your vendor's, you could maybe turn on the MySQL queries logging, so you can see all the SQL statements hitting your database, by monitoring the queries logs you can have accurate data about the database and know if it is refreshed and when. 
Implementing some kind of automatic methods to filter the queries you are interested in should allow you to know all you need. For example you could count the total amount of "INSERT" and "UPDATE" type quereis and draw graphs with that information.
This is just an idea, but maybe you could make use of some opensource monitoring tool to get the most value out of it and even draw graphs, reports...
Hope this helps.